# echo multidimensional array by grouping php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
$list = array(
        array(
        'header_name' => '1.',
        'header_database_name' => '2',
        'heading' => 'personal',
        ),

        array(
        'header_name' => '11. ',
        'header_database_name' => '22',
        'heading' => 'professional',        
        ),

        array(
        'header_name' => '33',
        'header_database_name' => '333',
        'heading' => 'personal',    
        ),
    );
```

foreach($list as $li)
            {
            ?>
"> ';}
else ($li['heading'] == 'performance')
{echo $li['header_name'].'
';}
}

I need to print this array by grouping it by heading for example the one with heading as personal should be displayed under the personal title i.e:

```
 Personal
    1
    33
    Professional
    11
```

my php code is like this

foreach($list as $li)
            {
            ?>
"> ';}
else ($li['heading'] == 'performance')
{echo $li['header_name'].'
';}
}

It is printing by group but i also need heading to be added but only one time at the top for example now if i add heading to it it prints as personal 1
professional 2
peronal 3

but i need as 
personal
1
2
professional 
2

Comment: Add your PHP code, and the expected output.

Comment: `Presonal 1 33` - strange output, can you elaborate it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort array if you want grouping of data, use `usort`

```
function headingSort ($x, $y) {
    return strcasecmp($x['heading'], $y['heading']);
}

usort($myArray, 'headingSort');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($list as $k=>$v)
{
    if(!in_array($v['header_name'], $new_array))
        $new_array[$v['heading']][] = $v['header_name'];
    else
        $new_array[$v['heading']] = $v['header_name'];
}
print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$list = array(
    array(
    'header_name' => '1.',
    'header_database_name' => '2',
    'heading' => 'personal',
    ),
    array(
    'header_name' => '11. ',
    'header_database_name' => '22',
    'heading' => 'professional',        
    ),
    array(
    'header_name' => '33',
    'header_database_name' => '333',
    'heading' => 'personal',    
    )
);

$personal = array();
$professional = array();

for($i=0;$i<count($list);$i++){
    if($list[$i]['heading']=="professional"){
        array_push($professional,$list[$i]);
    }else{
        array_push($personal,$list[$i]);
    }
}
$new = array(
        "personal"=>$personal,
        "professional"=>$professional
    );
echo "<pre>";
print_r($new);
```

Result will be like :

```
Array
(
[personal] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [header_name] => 1.
                [header_database_name] => 2
                [heading] => personal
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [header_name] => 33
                [header_database_name] => 333
                [heading] => personal
            )

    )

[professional] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [header_name] => 11. 
                [header_database_name] => 22
                [heading] => professional
            )

    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `array_column`(available since PHP 5.5), `array_unique`, `array_keys` and `implode` functions:

```
$headings = array_column($list, 'heading', 'header_name');

foreach (array_unique($headings) as $v) {
    echo ucfirst($v). PHP_EOL;
    echo implode("\n", array_keys($headings, $v)). PHP_EOL;    
}
```

The output:

```
Personal
1
33
Professional
11
```